# Replacing tile on front edge of tub that has sunk, but not enough room to attach drywall/cement board

Tags: bathroom, tile, bathtub, gap, filling

[**Album of area in question**](https://imgur.com/a/kpQhxc5)

We purchased our home with this known area of broken tile. *Eventually* the entire original mid-70s bathroom will be gutted and remodeled, but in the meantime, I'm looking for a solution that will:

1. waterproof the gap between the tub front wall edge (that is not plumb from previous water damage damaging the subfloor under this corner of the tub, causing the tub to sink) and the wall edge (which sits ~1/2 in. out further than the tub front wall)
2. allow us to re-tile going down to the floor to match the shape of the existing border tile
3. without ripping entire walls down, keeping work to a minimum, until we're financially ready to redo the entire bathroom

I was thinking of cutting out the broken tiles and thin set to create a clean edge, then just jam a bunch of thin set or joint compound into the crack to create a solid surface to lay thin set and tile onto, trimming the tile sides that will be contacting the front tub wall to account for the non-plumb tub wall. Then caulking the tile edge to the tub front and call it a day.

Comment: An expanding caulk, such as urethane foam, https://www.homedepot.com/s/urethane%20foam%20sealant?NCNI-5, might help prevent more water infiltration, though not a permanent fix.

Comment: How good do you need this temporary fix to look?  Do you have a problem with simply duct taping over it (paint it to match if you care that much)?  Why do you have masking tape on the bottom?